# Error while running chromedriver: "/lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found" in CentOS6

Tags: glibc, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to launch chromedriver on CentOS 6. More about the OS

```
<code>[root@localhost bin]# uname --all
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Feb 22 00:31:26 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux</code>
```

It throws the following error:

`` [root@localhost bin]# ./chromedriver 
./chromedriver: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by ./chromedriver) ``

./chromedriver: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by ./chromedriver)

./chromedriver: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by ./chromedriver)

Looking at some other responses and websites, I tried to upgrade gcc but `yum install gcc`  would not upgrade saying that the package is already at the latest version.

I don't want to touch the package manually so I am looking for other ways to upgrade it.

Also, if someone knows any other way around to launch chromedriver, please share it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> `/lib64/libc.so.6: version GLIBC_2.15`

The binary you are trying to run was built on a GLIBC-2.15 based system. It will not run on any system with older GLIBC (and your GLIBC is older than 2.14).

> `/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version GLIBCXX_3.4.15`

Likewise, your binary requires `libstdc++.so.6` 3.4.15 or above (3.4.15 corresponds to GCC 4.6).

You need to run this binary on a newer system, or to get that binary built for an older one.

> And where can I find an OS with GLIBC-2.15

Use [distrowatch.com](http://distrowatch.com). For example, this [link](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=centos) shows that there are no CentOS distributions that fit the bill, but [Fedora](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=fedora) 17 and later are sufficiently new.

Comment: And where can I find an OS with GLIBC-2.15?

Answer (score 0):

Actually ,  There is a way  to  run  both chrome and chromedriver  on amazon linux, centos 6.x and rhel. basic idea  to  use libs from a newer os.

See the  fully  automated script here 
https://github.com/staier/chromedriver-centos6-installation