# GLIBC 2.14 not found - Jenkins android gradle build while updating SDK & build tools

Tags: android, jenkins, glibc

Below is the error I have when I run a build script doing downloads of updated SDK and tools(25) manually,  since Jenkins build system in our server is yet to be updated with latest SDK and tools, I know it may be happening because build system supports only versions older to GLIBC_2.14.The guys who are incharge of jenkins build server in our company are delaying their update and hence, Any solution other than updating GLIBC_2.14 on server would be great.Below is the Console output from jenkins build.

```
      compileDevDebugAidl/opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/25.0.2/aidl: 
      /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by 
      /opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/25.0.2/aidl)
      /opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/25.0.2/aidl: /lib64/libc.so.6: 
      version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /opt/android-sdk-
      linux/build-tools/25.0.2/lib64/libc++.so)

      Execution failed for task ':projectName:compileDevDebugAidl'.
      > java.lang.RuntimeException: 
       com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
       org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 
      '/opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/25.0.2/aidl'' finished with non-
      zero exit value 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [/lib64/libc.so.6: version \`GLIBC\_2.14' not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42433530/lib64-libc-so-6-version-glibc-2-14-not-found)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know it may be happening because build system supports only versions older to GLIBC_2.14.

No: it's happening because the SDK you are trying to use: `/opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/25.0.2/aidl` *requires* `GLIBC-2.14` or newer, and the host you are trying to use it on has an older GLIBC version.

If you want to use that SDK, you *must* update your system with GLIBC-2.14.

Other solutions [are possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617), but are significantly more complicated.