# Issue with the GLIBC version on raspberry pie

Tags: raspberry-pi3, glibc, dlib

I'm trying to run the [face recognition](https://gist.github.com/ageitgey/1ac8dbe8572f3f533df6269dab35df65) framework on my raspberry pie model 3B. After completing the installation I get the following error when trying to execute the example code with `python3 facerec_on_raspberry_pi.py`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "facerec_on_raspberry_pi.py", line 9, in <module>
    import face_recognition
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/face_recognition/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .api import load_image_file, face_locations, batch_face_locations, face_landmarks, face_encodings, compare_faces, face_distance
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/face_recognition/api.py", line 4, in <module>
    import dlib
ImportError: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dlib.cpython-36m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so)
```

Here are some specs about my raspberry:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

```
Debian version 9.8
```

```
Linux raspberrypi 4.14.79-v7+ #1159 SMP Sun Nov 4 17:50:20 GMT 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Output of `ldd --version`

```
ldd (Debian GLIBC 2.24-11+deb9u4) 2.24
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

Output of `/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6`

```
GNU C Library (Debian GLIBC 2.24-11+deb9u4) stable release version 2.24, by Roland McGrath et al.
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Compiled by GNU CC version 6.3.0 20170516.
Available extensions:
    crypt add-on version 2.1 by Michael Glad and others
    GNU Libidn by Simon Josefsson
    Native POSIX Threads Library by Ulrich Drepper et al
    BIND-8.2.3-T5B
libc ABIs: UNIQUE
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.debian.org/Bugs/>.
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of CPython (specifically `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dlib.cpython-36m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so`) that you have installed is *incompatible* with your system (requires GLIBC 2.27, while you only have GLIBC 2.24).

You must either upgrade installed GLIBC, or use a different build of CPython.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42463268/50617).

Comment: i just built cpython on that device https://stackoverflow.com/a/64737929/4933053 and still glibc is incompatible, how come since the ./configure  should figure it out