# how to update python in raspberry pi

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I need python newest version in raspberry pi.
I tried `apt install python3 3.8`
 `apt install python3` but this didnot work.
And I also needed to update my raspberry pi python **IDLE**

Comment: https://www.ramoonus.nl/2020/10/06/how-to-install-python-3-9-on-raspberry-pi/

Comment: I would recommend using a python version manager such as pyenv. Don't try to change default python's as that can break the OS.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

First update the Raspbian.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install the prerequisites that will make any further installation of Python and/or packages much smoother.

```
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential tk-dev libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libreadline6-dev libdb5.3-dev libgdbm-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev libbz2-dev libexpat1-dev liblzma-dev zlib1g-dev libffi-dev
```

And then install Python, maybe by downloading a compressed file?

example 1 :

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.0/Python-3.8.0.tgz
```

Extract the folder :

```
sudo tar zxf Python-3.8.0.tgz
```

Move into the folder :

```
cd Python-3.8.0
```

Initial configuration :

```
sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations
```

Run the makefile inside the folder with the mentioned parameters :

```
sudo make -j 4
```

Run again the makefile this time installing directly the package :

```
sudo make altinstall
```

Maybe You already did it but You don't know how to setup the new version as a default version of the system?

Check first that it has been installed :

```
python3.8 -V
```

Send a strong command to .bashrc telling him who (which version) is in charge of Python

```
echo "alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3.8" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Again! Tell him because .bashrc has to understand! I am joking - You have to source the file so the changes can be applied immediately :

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

And then check that Your system changed the default version of Python to Python 3.8

```
python -V
```

The failure depends on many factors : what dependencies are installed, what are the packages added to the source_list.d, some inconvenient coming up during the installation. All may give you more information than you think, just read carefully.
Hope it helped.

Comment: I guess this is old. But isn't there a more... normal... way to update a required program? I'm new to Pi and by extension linux but this is more like a final year project. Is there really no decent/normal way for linux to update a python version? It feels like it's overcomplicated just for fun.  I guess I'm more used to there being 1-3 commands to update a library not a whole essay that I need to rewrite from memory on a different machine (pi doesn't do well with browsers)(ram) I don't know what the constraints are but this totally feel waaaaaay out of necessary bounds. But hey, this is linux.

Comment: Thanks Xerozz, amazing answer with detailed / kind explanation, which are very valuable for newbies like myself. Cheers.

Comment: Linux is painful.

Comment: Ah, of course. The everyone's favorite "easy, beginner friendly" programming language. Just compile it from source to update, no big deal... Is this truly the simplest solution?

Comment: This is because the latest version of python isn't on the raspberrypi repo's (I just checked and it's still on 3.7?!?!?). I would poke them about this. Python is a very common tool on rasppi's so the fact they do not keep the repos up to date is mind blowing.

Answer (score 5):

To all of you who got problem with freezing RPi 3 in step:

```
sudo make -j 4
```

just change it to:

```
sudo make -j 2
```

or simply:

```
sudo make
```

Best regards

Comment: If you want to suggest an answer like this, please also give your reasoning. Is this a workaround to a temporary bug? Or is it always necessary to do this? What does the -j flag do?

Comment: @AlexSpurling It specifies the number of CPU threads to use. This thread will explain: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15289250/using-make-with-j4-or-j8/15295032#15295032

Answer (score 1):

Follow below commands to install the version which you want:

```
tar xf Python-3.x.x.tar.xz
cd Python-3.x.x
./configure --enable-optimizations
make
sudo make install
```

once completed run `python -V`