# trying to update python on raspberry pi

Tags: python

Im new to this and am trying to install python and pip on my Raspi. I have followed the answer to this question,

[how to update python in raspberry pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64718274/how-to-update-python-in-raspberry-pi)

all good till i run this command

```
source ~./bashrc
```

which returns

```
bash: ~./bashrc: No such file or directory
```

If I run this command

```
ls -la ~/ | more
```

I can see the file, but what do i do to put this right and get my raspi to use Python3.8?

Comment: it should be ~/.bashrc the dot after the slash

Comment: All good now thank you