# How to install AWS CLI on Raspberry?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, raspberry-pi

I am trying to install AWS CLI from Amazon on my Raspbian (Rpi 3 B) following [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-linux.html#install-linux-bundled)
and i'm getting this error:

```
    sudo ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
Deprecated Python version detected: Python 2.7
Starting July 15, 2021, the AWS CLI will no longer support this version of Python. To continue receiving service updates, bug fixes, and security updates please upgrade to Python 3.6 or later. More information can be found here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/announcing-end-of-support-for-python-2-7-in-aws-sdk-for-python-and-aws-cli-v1/
Running cmd: /usr/bin/python virtualenv.py --no-download --python /usr/bin/python /usr/local/aws
Running cmd: /usr/local/aws/bin/pip install --no-binary :all: --no-cache-dir --no-index --find-links file://. setuptools_scm-3.3.3.tar.gz
Running cmd: /usr/local/aws/bin/pip install --no-binary :all: --no-cache-dir --no-index --find-links file://. wheel-0.33.6.tar.gz
Running cmd: /usr/local/aws/bin/pip install --no-binary :all: --no-build-isolation --no-cache-dir --no-index  --find-links file:///home/pi/awscli-bundle/packages awscli-1.19.84.tar.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./awscli-bundle/install", line 264, in <module>
    main()
  File "./awscli-bundle/install", line 244, in main
    opts.bin_location):
  File "./awscli-bundle/install", line 194, in create_symlink
    os.symlink(real_location, symlink_name)
OSError: [Errno 17] File exists
```

Overall i have python 2.7 and 3.7 and I tried to install with particular 3.7 version but it didn't work at all.

Comment: You should probably install v2 instead. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-linux.html

Comment: What os are you using? Usually awscli is in standard repos.

Comment: Try updating python to version 3.8 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64718274/how-to-update-python-in-raspberry-pi

Comment: @AKX V2 doesn;t work on 32 bit Raspbian best regards

Comment: Well, then you can just `python3 -m pip install awscli`...